# Expand/Collapse a div element?

Tags: javascript, html, yui

I want to show a content box (say a div) only up to a specified height by default. There will be a link like "More/Less" at the bottom which when clicked, I want to show the full content of the content box. Then the "more" name of the link will change to "less". Please give some hint.
Is it possible to do in YUI or better if standalone JS?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Anim module in YUI provides what you need. If you look here at the reversing  [animation example](http://yuilibrary.com/yui/docs/anim/reverse.html) it shows how to do that. Here is the source from that.

```
<div id="demo" class="yui3-module">
<div class="yui3-hd">
    <h3>Reversing an Animation</h3>
</div>
<div class="yui3-bd">
    <p>Click the icon in the header to toggle the element's height.</p>
</div>
</div>
<p>This is placeholder text used to demonstrate how the above animation affects subsequent content.</p> 


<script type="text/javascript">type="text/javascript">
YUI().use('anim', function(Y) {
var module = Y.one('#demo');

// add fx plugin to module body
var content = module.one('.yui3-bd').plug(Y.Plugin.NodeFX, {
    from: { height: 0 },
    to: {
        height: function(node) { // dynamic in case of change
            return node.get('scrollHeight'); // get expanded height (offsetHeight may be zero)
        }
    },

    easing: Y.Easing.easeOut,
    duration: 0.5
});

var onClick = function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    module.toggleClass('yui3-closed');
    content.fx.set('reverse', !content.fx.get('reverse')); // toggle reverse 
    content.fx.run();
};

// use dynamic control for dynamic behavior
var control = Y.Node.create(
    '<a title="collapse/expand element" class="yui3-toggle">' +
        '<em>toggle</em>' +
    '</a>'
);

// append dynamic control to header section
module.one('.yui3-hd').appendChild(control);
control.on('click', onClick);

});
</script>
```

Comment: yea I was looking for this. Thanks Kevin.

Answer (score 5):

Ok, didn't have much time before an answer got accepted, but here is the general principle of performing more/less in just plain ol' javascript, no libraries.

CSS

```css
p.more {
    margin: 5px;
}
p.less {
    height: 1em;
    overflow: hidden;
}
div.block {
    width: 500px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 1px;
    border-radius: 3px;
    background-color: OldLace;
    box-shadow: 2px 3px 5px DimGray;
    margin: 10px;
}
p.continued {
    font-size: 10px;
    margin: -5px 0px 0px 5px;
}
p.continued:after {
    content: "[...]";
}
p.continuedHide {
    display: none;
}
div.control {
    text-align: center;
    width: 3em;
    height: 1em;
    border-radius: 10px;
    border: 1px solid ;
    margin: 5px;
    padding: 0px 0px 5px 0px;
    background-color: LightGray;
    box-shadow: 2px 3px 5px DimGray;
}
div.control:after {
    content: "more";
}
div.controlLess:after {
    content: "less";
}
div.control:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

HTML

```js
<p class="more">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat, vel illum dolore eu feugiat nulla facilisis. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat, vel illum dolore eu feugiat nulla facilisis.</p>
<p class="more">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat, vel illum dolore eu feugiat nulla facilisis. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat, vel illum dolore eu feugiat nulla facilisis.</p>
<p class="more">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat, vel illum dolore eu feugiat nulla facilisis. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat, vel illum dolore eu feugiat nulla facilisis.</p>
```

Javascript

```js
Array.prototype.forEach.call(document.getElementsByClassName("more"), function (more) {
    more.classList.toggle("less");

    var element = document.createElement("div");

    element.className = "block";
    more.parentNode.insertBefore(element, more).appendChild(more);

    element = document.createElement("p");
    element.className = "continued";
    more.parentNode.appendChild(element);

    element = document.createElement("div");
    element.className = "control";
    element.addEventListener("click", function () {
        this.classList.toggle("controlLess");
        more.classList.toggle("less");
        this.previousSibling.classList.toggle("continuedHide");
    }, false);

    more.parentNode.appendChild(element);
});
```

On <kbd>[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Xotic750/FLUKR/)</kbd>

You can pretty much style it as you like, simply use the css, set the height when maximised and add scroll to overflow. Change colors, add CSS3 animations etc etc

This is an example of capping the max height and auto adding scrollbars.

```css
p.more {
    margin: 5px;
    height: 10em;
    overflow: auto;
}
```

On <kbd>[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Xotic750/eG9xH/)</kbd>

This is the minimum CSS required for it to work

```css
p.less {
    height: 1em;
    overflow: hidden;
}
p.continued:after {
    content: "[...]";
}
p.continuedHide {
    display: none;
}
div.control:after {
    content: "more";
}
div.controlLess:after {
    content: "less";
}
div.control:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

On <kbd>[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Xotic750/J3u4j/)</kbd>

Ok, so I guess I went a little crazy and made this into a library, I will probably upload it to git-hub or google-code later. It should be cross-browser, at least what I am able to test. It doesn't use any extra external libraries, but I have demonstrated how it could be used with jquery too. The CSS that I am posting is not minimal but is what I am using with the demo. You should also be able to use the markup created for the <kbd>[jQuery More/Less Text](http://shakenandstirredweb.com/240/jquery-moreless-text)</kbd>

The basic markup structure required is

```html
<div class="more-less">
    <div class="more-block">
        <p>The Content</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

And this CSS and Javascript

CSS

```css
/* More Or Less CSS v1.1
 *
 * Add functionality that only displays the first few lines of a block of content
 * with a 'More/Less' link at the bottom, which when clicked, will expand or
 * contract the content. Written with cross-browser compatibility in mind and
 * does not require any external libraries.>
 *
 * Copyright (C) 2013  Graham Fairweather (a.k.a: Xotic750)
 *
 * This program is free software: you can redistribute it and/or modify
 * it under the terms of the GNU General Public License as published by
 * the Free Software Foundation, either version 3 of the License, or
 * (at your option) any later version.
 *
 * This program is distributed in the hope that it will be useful,
 * but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
 * MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.  See the
 * GNU General Public License for more details.
 *
 * You should have received a copy of the GNU General Public License
 * along with this program.  If not, see <http://www.gnu.org/licenses/>.
 */

div.more-less {
    width: 500px;
    height: auto;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 1px;
    border-radius: 3px;
    background-color: OldLace;
    box-shadow: 2px 3px 5px DimGray;
    margin: 10px;
}
div.more-block {
    margin: 5px;
}
div.more-block-less {
    height: 3em;
    overflow: hidden;
}
div.more-less-continued {
    position: relative;
    text-align: right;
    width: 1em;
    height: 1em;
    bottom: 1em;
    font-size: 0.8em;
    margin: 1em;
    float: right;
    line-height: 1em;
}
div.more-less-continued-hide {
    display: none;
}
div.more-less-control {
    text-align: center;
    width: 3em;
    height: 1em;
    border-radius: 10px;
    border: 1px solid;
    margin: 5px;
    background-color: LightGray;
    box-shadow: 2px 3px 5px DimGray;
    cursor: pointer;
    line-height: 1em;
}
div.more-block > * {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    margin: auto;
}
```

Javascript

```js
/*jslint maxerr: 50, indent: 4, browser: true, bitwise: true */
/*global tokenList */

/* More Or Less v1.4
 *
 * home: http://code.google.com/p/more-or-less/
 *
 * Add functionality that only displays the first few lines of a block of content
 * with a 'More/Less' link at the bottom, which when clicked, will expand or
 * contract the content. Written with cross-browser compatibility in mind and
 * now uses the DOMTokenList project for dealing with classList.
 *
 * http://code.google.com/p/domtokenlist/
 *
 * Copyright (C) 2013  Graham Fairweather (a.k.a: Xotic750)
 *
 * This program is free software: you can redistribute it and/or modify
 * it under the terms of the GNU General Public License as published by
 * the Free Software Foundation, either version 3 of the License, or
 * (at your option) any later version.
 *
 * This program is distributed in the hope that it will be useful,
 * but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
 * MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.  See the
 * GNU General Public License for more details.
 *
 * You should have received a copy of the GNU General Public License
 * along with this program.  If not, see <http://www.gnu.org/licenses/>.
 */

var moreLess = (function (tokenList) {
    "use strict";

    var toStringFN = {}.toString,
        moreLessClassListProperty = "classList",
        classNameProperty = "className",
        texts = {
            "continued": "[...]",
            "more": "more",
            "less": "less"
        };

    function addEvent(node, type, func) {
        var handler;

        if (node.addEventListener) {
            node.addEventListener(type, func, false);
        } else if (node.attachEvent) {
            node["e" + type + func] = func;
            node[type + func] = function () {
                node["e" + type + func](window.event);
            };

            node.attachEvent("on" + type, node[type + func]);
        } else {
            handler = node["on" + type];
            if (typeof handler === "function") {
                node["on" + type] = function (evt) {
                    handler(evt);
                    func(evt);
                };
            } else {
                node["on" + type] = func;
            }
        }
    }

    function addTokenList(element) {
        if (!element[moreLessClassListProperty]) {
            tokenList.addTokenList(element, classNameProperty, moreLessClassListProperty);
        }
    }

    function getElementsByClassName(node, className) {
        var elements = node.getElementsByTagName("*"),
            length = elements.length,
            array = [],
            i = 0,
            element;

        while (i < length) {
            element = elements[i];
            addTokenList(element);
            if (element[moreLessClassListProperty].contains(className)) {
                array.push(element);
            }

            i += 1;
        }

        return array;
    }

    function createElement(content) {
        var moreLess = document.createElement("div"),
            element = document.createElement("div");

        addTokenList(element);
        element[moreLessClassListProperty].add("more-block", "more-block-less");
        if (typeof content === "string") {
            element.innerHTML = content;
        } else {
            element.appendChild(content);
        }

        addTokenList(moreLess);
        moreLess[moreLessClassListProperty].add("more-less", "more-less-added");
        moreLess.appendChild(element);

        element = document.createElement("div");
        addTokenList(element);
        element[moreLessClassListProperty].add("more-less-continued");
        element.appendChild(document.createTextNode(texts.continued));
        moreLess.appendChild(element);

        element = document.createElement("div");
        addTokenList(element);
        element[moreLessClassListProperty].add("more-less-control");
        element.appendChild(document.createTextNode(texts.more));
        moreLess.appendChild(element);

        return moreLess;
    }

    function addMarkup() {
        var moreLesses = getElementsByClassName(document, "more-less"),
            length = moreLesses.length,
            i = 0,
            node,
            child,
            element;

        while (i < length) {
            node = moreLesses[i];
            addTokenList(node);
            if (!node[moreLessClassListProperty].contains("more-less-added")) {
                node[moreLessClassListProperty].add("more-less-added");
                child = node.children[0];
                addTokenList(child);
                child[moreLessClassListProperty].add("more-block-less");

                element = document.createElement("div");
                addTokenList(element);
                element[moreLessClassListProperty].add("more-less-continued");
                element.appendChild(document.createTextNode(texts.continued));
                node.appendChild(element);

                element = document.createElement("div");
                addTokenList(element);
                element[moreLessClassListProperty].add("more-less-control");
                element.appendChild(document.createTextNode(texts.more));
                node.appendChild(element);
            }

            i += 1;
        }
    }

    function bind() {
        addEvent(document, "click", function onClicked(evt) {
            var target = evt.target,
                parent = target.parentNode,
                moreBlock = parent.children[0],
                continueds = getElementsByClassName(parent, "more-less-continued"),
                length,
                continued,
                item;

            if (moreBlock.nodeName === "DIV" && moreBlock[moreLessClassListProperty].contains("more-block")) {
                length = continueds.length;
                item = 0;
                while (item < length) {
                    continued = continueds[item];
                    if (continued[moreLessClassListProperty].contains("more-less-continued-hide")) {
                        continued[moreLessClassListProperty].remove("more-less-continued-hide");
                        if (item === 0) {
                            moreBlock[moreLessClassListProperty].add("more-block-less");
                            target.firstChild.nodeValue = texts.more;
                        }
                    } else {
                        continued[moreLessClassListProperty].add("more-less-continued-hide");
                        if (item === 0) {
                            moreBlock[moreLessClassListProperty].remove("more-block-less");
                            target.firstChild.nodeValue = texts.less;
                        }
                    }

                    item += 1;
                }
            }
        });
    }

    function setTexts(object) {
        if (toStringFN.call(object) === "[object Object]") {
            var i;

            for (i in object) {
                if (object.hasOwnProperty(i)) {
                    if (texts[i] && typeof object[i] === "string") {
                        texts[i] = object[i];
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return {
        "setTexts": setTexts,
        "bind": bind,
        "addMarkup": addMarkup,
        "createElement": createElement
    };
}(tokenList));
```

Then there is the demonstration Javascript

```js
// These are the default texts, but using this method you can change them to what you want
moreLess.setTexts({
    "continued": "[...]",
    "more": "more",
    "less": "less"
});

// This method adds the required click listener to the document
moreLess.bind();
// This method causes a search of the document, and any matching markup will have
// the additional markup added
moreLess.addMarkup();

// Now for some dynamic examples

// Some text we will use
var text = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat, vel illum dolore eu feugiat nulla facilisis. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat, vel illum dolore eu feugiat nulla facilisis.";

// Demonstartions

// Using dynamically created node with the `moreLess.createElement` method
var element = document.createElement("p");

element.appendChild(document.createTextNode(text));
document.body.appendChild(moreLess.createElement(element));

// Using dynamically created html text with the `moreLess.createElement` method
document.body.appendChild(moreLess.createElement("<p>" + text + "<p>"));

// Using dynamically created jquery node and jquery html text with the
// `moreLess.createElement` method
$(document.body).append(moreLess.createElement($("<p>").text(text).get(0)));
$(document.body).append(moreLess.createElement($("<p>").text(text).html()));

// Using html text with the jquery `append` method, then executing `moreLess.addMarkup`
// method upon a button click to add the additional markup.
var html = '<div class="more-less"> <div class="more-block" style="overflow: hidden;"> <img alt="Car 1" src="http://img130.imageshack.us/img130/4296/v2gr0wd.jpg"> <h2>Lorem ipsum dolor</h2> <p>' + text + '</p> </div> </div>'

$(document.body).append(html);
$(document.body).append($("<button>").text("Add Markup").click(moreLess.addMarkup));
```

Anyway, you can see the demonstration on <kbd>[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Xotic750/uu9Rk/)</kbd>

I am going to stop playing now, though I will try to add some comments ;) Once I upload it somewhere then I will post a link to it back here.

Here is the <kbd>[More Or Less](https://code.google.com/archive/p/more-or-less)</kbd> project.

**Update:** Have now incorporated my other project <kbd>[DOMTokenList](https://code.google.com/archive/p/domtokenlist)</kbd> and updated the demonstration.

[image]
<sub>(source: [ohloh.net](https://www.ohloh.net/p/more-or-less/widgets/project_thin_badge.gif))</sub>
[image]
<sub>(source: [ohloh.net](https://www.ohloh.net/p/domtokenlist/widgets/project_thin_badge.gif))</sub>

Comment: I really appreciate the reply Xotic750. And looks like I have to change my mind as this fits best the requirement I specified.

Comment: No problem, it was kind of fun :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `jQuery More/Less` plugin.It is a beautiful plugin

[**SEE HERE**](http://shakenandstirredweb.com/240/jquery-moreless-text)

Comment: I used upvote actually! Is it showing down for you? Though I was waiting for some simple standalone JS script to do that.

Comment: I downvoted as a YUI or standalone solution was asked for, not a jquery plugin.